# Merging from a non-origin repository

Tags: git, github

I've forked a repo and need to keep it updated with changes from the original.

I have an upstream remote pointing at the original, and wondered if this workflow makes sense?  Any suggestions or improvements welcomed.

```
#from master branch I do..
git checkout -b new_branch

#do some work, commit my changes, then...
git fetch upstream master
git merge upstream/master
```

I'm sure I can rebase as well in this situation, and maybe that makes more sense, but wondered if the above will do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The above code is exactly how you keep your fork up to date.

Comment: Apparently I should get my eyes checked. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Learath2 no worries `:)`